# Python: Pandas: Matplotlib: Year over Year (x = month, y = donations for each year)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a simple dataset with one column = date (01/31/2014...01/31/2021) and the other column = value (45000, 45500, 50000...)

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 01/31/2014 | 450000 |

I am able to produce this by pivoting the data with x = month, y = donations per year:

[image]

But I really only want to do this for this year - 3 (2021, 2020, 2019, 2018).

I have spent a while searching but cannot figure out.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by plotting a pivot table.

```
pv = pd.pivot_table(df.loc[df.date >= '2018-01-01'], index=df.date.dt.month, columns=df.date.dt.year, values='value', aggfunc='sum')
pv.plot()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use like

```
df[df['date'] >= '01/01/2018']
```

Comment: This will not work, because `'01/01/2018'` is not a datetime format.

Comment: haha you right, my bad, I forgot to adjust that.